# Colorize part of text in PIXIJS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

How to make different color for some part of the text which is under/above image (Sprite)?
Example: https://clip2net.com/s/43y248h

The image moves dynamically and the text also should be colored dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use 2 text object:

- one under the image (black)
- one over the image (white)
- then mask the text over image with a shape of the size of the image
- pay attention to move text layer simultaneously

Check out this [simple demo](https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/puXlIAbEkhqtnD6KmrVbX) I've made for you:

```
// Create our application instance
var app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0xeeeeee
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Load the bunny texture
app.loader.add('bunny', 'https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/bunny.png')
    .load(startup);

function startup()
{
    let text = new PIXI.Text('This is a PixiJS text',{fontFamily : 'Arial', fontSize: 48, fill : 0x000000, align : 'center'});
    let text2 = new PIXI.Text('This is a PixiJS text',{fontFamily : 'Arial', fontSize: 48, fill : 0xFF0000, align : 'center'});
    let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/male-default-placeholder-avatar-profile-260nw-387516193.jpg');
    let sprite2 = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/male-default-placeholder-avatar-profile-260nw-387516193.jpg');
    text2.mask = sprite2;
    app.stage.addChild(text);
    app.stage.addChild(sprite);
    app.stage.addChild(sprite2);
    app.stage.addChild(text2);



    // Listen for animate update
    app.ticker.add(function(delta)
    {
        // your code
    });
}
```

Comment: How to do that 'then mask the text over image with a shape of the size of the image'

Comment: Basically, if you set myText.mask = mySprite the text will be clipped to the size of the sprite. Check out the mask example in pixiJS folder

Comment: I've added a simple example